# console.log method extraction from console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

Considering that `console` wasn't overriden and refers to native object, `console.log` method (and possibly others) is extracted from `console` object with

```
var log = obj.log = console.log;
// instead of console.log.bind(console)
log(...);
obj.log(...);
```

Is it 100% safe in terms of browser and Node compatibility?

A significant amount of JS examples (maybe too illustrative) with bound `console.log` suggests that it may be not.

Comment: Did you try it, does it work? What environment[s] are you running in?

Comment: That depends on the implementation, but a sane implementation would implement `log` as something like `this._write(log_level, msg, ...)`, i.e. a shorthand alias to another internal method. As such, `this` very likely must be preserved.

Comment: @epascarello Never had problems with it in actual FF and Chrome versions, but not sure about the rest.

Comment: @estus: I'm pretty sure in both node and Chrome it was (is?) a problem. In Opera 12 extraction worked.

Comment: It doesn't even work in Chrome. How can it be 100% safe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Browsers differ in their `console` implementations, it appears that WebKit/Blink-based browsers (Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari, etc) are the only ones that are uncomfortable with extracted `console` methods. For browser compatibility extracted methods have to be bound:

```
var log = console.log.bind(console);
```

Node has its own `console` implementation that relies on `this` but [pre-binds its methods](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v6.2.0/lib/console.js#L30-L35). It is safe to extract `console` methods in Node applications, the same applies to Electron's main process.

NW.js [replaces Node `console`](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Console-and-timers) with Chromium's:

> Node.js and Chromium each has its own implementation of setTimeout and console. Currently, for console, we use Chromium's implementation everywhere, because it can print in devtools and have more information exposed.

It is not safe to extract `console` methods in NW.js Node's context.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it 100% safe in terms of browser and Node compatibility?

It isn't.

- In Node.js console methods are bound to instance on method creation. [Relevant code in Node.js source](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/1c84579031e34326742c9c264f54625c5918197c/lib/console.js#L34).
- [Gecko](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e169c5fcb3ceaa196a273400a5d913b3f0c75de5/toolkit/modules/Console.jsm#L487) console method requires valid `this` (unbound methods are i).

I couldn't find `console` implementation in Chrome source.

Comment: Thanks for providing the link for Gecko, but I guess that the correct one is https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/e169c5fcb3ceaa196a273400a5d913b3f0c75de5/toolkit/modules/Console.jsm#L639-L644