# Bound console methods

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

To my knowledge, `console` methods are bound in most if not all modern JS engines.

```
var log = console.log;
log('foo');

window.addEventListener('load', console.log); // or any other API that accepts callbacks
```

will result in proper console output, at least in up-to-date Edge, Firefox and Chrome/Node.js versions, so it's relatively safe to rely on this behaviour in development environment.

Unfortunately, [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=console.log) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log#Browser_compatibility) don't cover this and potentially contain unverified information.

What are exact browser versions where this behaviour is supported?

Is this a part of any current standard or a proposal?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn Yes, I've linked it in the question. It says that console is supported since Safari 3 but I've checked 4 and I don't see a console at all there.

Comment: Yeah I don't know why I commented that, I even clicked on your link too beforehand.

Comment: BUt you were right, caniuse wasn't helpful at all in this case.

Comment: I'm surprised that such a basic and mandatory language feature [is not standarisized anywhere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)

Comment: @JonasW. MDN not linking it doesn't meant that [the standard](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) doesn't exist :-)

Comment: @bergi it links it, but the standard is somewhat not really a standard.

Comment: Closely related: [console.log method extraction from console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37426153/1048572)