# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning while no there is not promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lately, I get this error a lot while testing my code. Just now I am getting this error again trying to execute synchronous code containing an error:

```
(async function() {

  const characterProfile = await Model.findOne({'author': author.id}).catch(console.error);

  if (!characterProfile) {msg.reply('No characters satisfied your criteria.'); return;}

  var displayIndexes = charfields.isEqual("field", name); // <- error "name"

  console.log(displayIndexes);

})();
```

I understand there is an error, and it would be fine if it was just telling me there is a ReferenceError, but it says:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: name is not defined
>
> [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are
>   deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

So I am afraid that DeprecationWarning will ruin my code in future and that would be a disaster. `charfields.isEqual()` is not a promise, it is a forEach loop that returns an array of ids. Why do I get a promise error like there actually is a promise error?

Comment: That's because you're in an `async` function, which returns a promise.

Comment: @SLaks I see, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An async function returns a Promise.  You could demonstrate this by `catch`ing the result of calling your IIFE, e.g.

```
(async function() {

  const characterProfile = await Model.findOne({'author': author.id}).catch(console.error);

  if (!characterProfile) {msg.reply('No characters satisfied your criteria.'); return;}

  var displayIndexes = charfields.isEqual("field", name); // <- error "name"

  console.log(displayIndexes);

})().catch(err => console.log(err)); // Will log out the reference error
```

Essentially, your async function is equivalent to the following:

```
(function() {
  return Model.findOne({'author': author.id})
  .then(characterProfile => {
      if (!characterProfile) {msg.reply('No characters satisfied your criteria.'); return;}

      var displayIndexes = charfields.isEqual("field", name); // <- error "name"

      console.log(displayIndexes);
  })
  .catch(console.error);  
})();
```

A common way of dealing with this is to use try/catch:

```
(async function() {
  try {
    const characterProfile = await Model.findOne({'author': author.id}).catch(console.error);

    if (!characterProfile) {msg.reply('No characters satisfied your criteria.'); return;}

    var displayIndexes = charfields.isEqual("field", name); // <- error "name"

    console.log(displayIndexes);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})()
```

Comment: In Node, console methods are guaranteed to be bound to proper context, it's `.catch(console.log)`.

Comment: Thanks @estus helpful information. Do you know of any good resource as to which methods are auto bound in node or different browser environments? It's something that catches me out relatively frequently, e.g. `const map = new Map(); setTimeout(map.clear, 1000); ` failing. I usually pass a lambda callback as above, or explicitly `.bind` the function but often after breaking something first.

Comment: @AlexYoung Not much, still waiting for the answer even regarding this one, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660346/bound-console-methods . It's safe to use console methods in Node for sure, AIK they are de facto bound in *modern* browsers. No, you shouldn't expect this from `map.clear` or any other method that is related to some class instance. Usually the ones that are bound are static methods. You just know they are legit when you meet them in good code. E.g. `Date.now` and `Object` static methods are known for that.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you use the `async` keyword, you're creating at least 1 promise. Everything inside the async function really is part of the promise.

If you're using `async` everywhere and you have an entrypoint to your application that calls the 'main async' function, you can handle errors like such:

```
async main() {
   // Run your app
}

// Call main when your code executes:
main().catch( e => { // do something with 'e' });
```